# Database design: Organising items (movies) by genre

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I'm making a basic movie online store for a project and I want users to be able to select movies by genre, e.g.:

- All
- Terror
- Action
- Documentaries
- Sci-Fi
- ...

What is the best way to store movies in the database to match this structure.

**First Way**

Sort movies by genre and create separate tables, that is, a table for the action genre, one for documentaries, one for sci-fi and so with the others. With this approach, there would be no clear way to join the tables to produce the list of all movies

**Second Way**

Place all movies in a single table, place the genres in another table, and establish a foreign key relationship between the 2 based on genre

Or is there another better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not your first way: that's not a relational database as you duplicate like information.

2nd way is more appropriate if you're looking to be relational.
Movies in one table
MovieType in a second table.

Movies table contains a FK to MovieType which lists the names of the genre.

Comment: Then you think that create a third table that contains id_movie and id_genre is incorrect?

Comment: No it would be correct as well IF you want to allow movies to have multiple genre's.  IF you want to ONLY allow a movie to be in ONE Genre, then having the FK to movie is correct. If a movie can be in MULTIPLE genere's than a third table is correct.

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean genre, not gender. :)  I don't think peliculas have a gender.  Personally, I would create 3 tables.  Movies (Peliculas), Genre, and a lookup table with the Ids from both.  This would allow for a movie to show up in multiple searches - which you might want.  For example, a movie about The Beatles might be under both Music and Documentary genres, and this way it would show up if a user searched for either.

**Peliculas   (Table1)**

```
PeliculaId
other cols (name, etc)
```

**Genre (Table2)**

```
GenreId
GenreDescription
```

**PelGenre (Table3)**

```
PeliculaId FK
GenreId FK
```

**Peliculas**

```
------------
PeliculaId  Name                    Descript
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1  The Beatles Anthology    Documentary series on The Beatles career  
     2  The Shawshank Redemption 2 good guys in jail become friends and get back at everyone
     3  Star Wars        Farm Boy saves Galaxy
```

**Genre**

```
GenreId     Descript
----------------------------------
1           Action
2           Crime
3           Drama
4           ScienceFiction
5           Documentary
6           Music
```

**PelGenre**

```
PeliculaId      GenreId
------------------------
1               5
1               6
2               2
2               3
3               4
3               1
```

Comment: True xD I'm wrong to translate, but the way to organize the tables, is that I thought, thanks!

Comment: Thanks man! Ur answer worked but I use only two tables because each movie have one genre :) .. +1 for you!

Answer (score 2):

Have two tables; one for movies, one for genres.

```
Movies {id, title, genre_id}
Genres {id, name}
```

To query by genre:

```
SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE genre_id = ?
```

To query for all genres, just remove the genre_id part from the WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM Movies
```

Comment: almost all said the same thing and solved my problem, I'll give you +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

**Categories table**

```
name
id (unique)
```

**Movies Table**

```
id (unique, autoincremental)
other data
```

Relational table

**Cat_mov**

```
movie_id (the id of the movie)
cat_id (the id of the categorie)
```

Comment: Is the best way for a movie with multiple genres, but i use only one movie-one genre :)

Comment: You can think it both ways, Or a genre with multiple movies or a movie with multiple genres. Different implementation, same tables :)